# video keeps playing after close modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want my code to play a video but when I close the modal the music in the video still plays on the background.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>       
                <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using jquery to fix it but nothing happens.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $videoSrc;
    $('.btn-play').click(function () {
        $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
    });
    console.log($videoSrc);

    $('#videoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0");
    })

    $('#videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
    })
});
```

Comment: It's unclear if you need the modal again (or can rebuild it).  So you could just remove the iframe, eg:  `$("#videoModal").empty()`

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you can either stop or pause the video playing when the `hide.bs.modal` event fires.

You can do this by sending a `postMessage` to the `iframe` containing the embedded Youtube player. Note that the `enablejsapi=1` parameter **has** to be included in the embed URL for this to work.

Here's a simplified example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#" class="play-video">Play Video</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="stop-video">Stop Video</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="pause-video">Pause Video</a></div>

<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LDU_Txk06tM?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

```js
let videoIframeContent = $('#video')[0].contentWindow;

// stop 
videoIframeContent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"event": "command", "func": "stopVideo" }), '*');

// pause
videoIframeContent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"event": "command", "func": "pauseVideo" }), '*');
```

Here's a working demo in a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/uctknq37/) and the snippet editor is sandboxed and won't allow video.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the video wasn't stopped.

In the listener that listens to the `hide.bs.modal` event:

```js
const video = $('#video').get(0);
video.pause();
video.currentTime = 0;
```

Comment: This isn't going to work if the iframe is cross domain, which given that the OP appears to be calling the embedded Youtube player, it will be.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to use video tag instead of iframe to control video follow [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop)

Comment: Please include a small example / your answer in the post. Links to demos / webpages / images / videos can go stale. For more information you can read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).